# Zend Framework and Oracle. How to upload and display images in the database?

Tags: oracle, zend-framework, extjs3

Can someone provide an example of code to add and display in an Oracle database from the Zend Framework?

I do so:
    $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$this->_name." (NAME, LOGO)
    VALUES ('".$params['name']."' , :image)");

```
$lob = oci_new_descriptor($db->getConnection(), OCI_D_LOB);
$stmt->bindParam(':image', $lob, OCI_B_CLOB, -1);
$lob->writeTemporary($this->saveFile($file)); // $this->saveFile($file) - file content
$stmt->execute();
$lob->close();
```

Not worked. What i do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Why put the image in the database? Load the image to a file server, and save the location of the image to the database

Comment: customer wants to make the images stored in the database)

Comment: @Andrei Will you store your video files in database if customer wants to?

Answer (score 0):

**decided** 
[example](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.oci-new-descriptor.php)